# Is an ubuntu ISO available with a preloaded KVM installation?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

Looking for an Ubuntu ISO that can be loaded on a flash drive or on MacOS or PC that has a graphical KVM frontend.

Comment: What do you mean by graphical KVM frontend? you are looking for qemu?

Comment: By graphical I mean no command prompts or terminal commands needed.

Comment: I don't have much in the way of recommendations for software that will run on Mac OS - I have seen posts that VirtualBox runs pretty well there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ISO available with KVM pre-installed, however you can grab a copy of any supported Ubuntu versions, create a Live persistences USB using that ISO, and then install: `kvm-qemu` to use KVM also install the `virt-manager`, it will allow you to manage virtual machines using a graphical environment:

```
sudo apt install kvm-qemu virt-manager
```

[image]

*Picture from fedoraproject*

Comment: The OP wants to use MacOS or Windows as host...

Comment: @CharlesGreen Updated the answer to address the flash drive section ;)

Comment: Hm.  Maybe I'm reading the question backwards.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The kernel component of KVM is included in mainline Linux, as of 2.6.20. The userspace component of KVM is included in mainline QEMU, as of 1.3.